# Passing values between pages using jquery php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I used this code to get the value of multiple checkbox. I want any one to guide me to a tutorial that can show me how to do it without refreshing the page. Below is my code.

```
<form action="#" method="post">
<input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="C/C++"><label>C/C++</label><br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="Java"><label>Java</label><br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="PHP"><label>PHP</label><br/>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
  if(!empty($_POST['check_list'])){
    // Loop to store and display values of individual checked checkbox.
    foreach($_POST['check_list'] as $selected){
    echo $selected."</br>";
    }
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: where is jquery code?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

My guess is he knows how to do that withj PHP but doesn't how to with jQuery. So here goes:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="choicesForm" action="#" method="post">
    <input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="C/C++"><label>C/C++</label><br/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="Java"><label>Java</label><br/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="PHP"><label>PHP</label><br/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
<script>
    jQuery('#choicesForm').submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        selectedItems = [];
        jQuery('#choicesForm input[name="check_list[]"]:checked').each(function(index){
           selectedItems.push(jQuery(this).val());
        });

        alert('selected items: ' + selectedItems.join(', '));
    });
</script>
</html>
```

If PASSING is the core problem, the PHP should simply return

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
  if(!empty($_POST['check_list'])){
    echo json_encode(join('<br/>',$_POST['check_list']));
  }
}
```

Which should be read by Jquery using AJAX.
Result of ajax should be read by catching the PHP response with `done`. Explained in detail on http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/